# Spring boot retrieve resource from custom location

Tags: java, spring, file, spring-boot, resources

I have a custom resource handler in my application set like this :

```
  @Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
     registry
        .addResourceHandler("/external/**")
        .addResourceLocations("file:" + sharedResourceRootPath);
}
```

My mapping

```
    @Value("${spring.configurateur.data}")
    private String sharedResourceRootPath;

    // with spring.configurateur.data: C:/webapp/data
```

I can't find a way to retrieve the resource under this location. My code :

```
        try(InputStream ir = ResourceUtils.getURL("external", "parentDir", "conf.csv").openStream();) {......}
```

Not found ...

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\external\parentDir\conf.csv (Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable)
```

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the file under `C:\webapp\data\external\parentDir\conf.csv`? Or which file exactly? Because `Paths.get(...)` will create a path relative to the current directory if you do not start with a file system root.

Comment: Yes I want to retrieve the file C:\webapp\data\parentDir\conf.csv. I edited the Question and deleted the Paths.get part. Thx

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
Path p = Paths.get(sharedResourceRootPath, "external", "parentDir", "conf.csv");
InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(p);
```

to retrieve an inputstream for a file relative to you `sharedResourceRootPath`.

Or just use

```
try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(
        Paths.get(sharedResourceRootPath, "external", "parentDir", "conf.csv")) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: My issue is to retrieve a file as a resource, not just loagin a File from disk. I thought that by putting a custom resource handler It would allow me to retrieve the files under c:/webapp/data as resrouces by just using the path "external/myfilename".